# Bind specific usb out

Tags: mount, block-device

How can I bind specific usb out to specific `/dev/sd*` value?

Each time that I plugged in some device in specific usb out it binds to different `/dev/sd*` location. How can I avoid it to set mounting option in `fstab`?

Comment: Do you want to bind to a specific *device name* an *usb port* or an *usb device*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're running Linux, [Udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) decides what device name to assign to a block device.

The Udev rule `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules` tries to assign names for each block device that depend on a unique identifier of the filesystem that it contains. The directories `/dev/disk/by-*` contain symbolic links to the actual device file (e.g. `/dev/sd*`). Mount one of these, e.g. `/dev/disk/by-label/joe_photos` or `/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ACME1789-ZRM3OTV8KRJ1OAAN-part7`.

If you want to mount the device automatically, you can do it by writing a `udev` rule, like this:

```
KERNEL=="sd?", PROGRAM=="/sbin/blkid -o value -s UUID %N1", RESULT=="1234-5678", SYMLINK+="removable/mydisk", RUN="mkdir /media/mydisk && mount /dev/removable/mydisk /media/mydisk"
```

Don't forget to unmount the device before unplugging it. Udev can't help there since it can only react after the unplugging.

Run `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdz42` to see how you might be able to identify the specified disk.